# Ошибка в коде .format язык питон

Tags: python

## Банковский вклад

```
X = 321768
Y = 0.42
P = 1.12
print('({} + {}) * {} ').format(X, Y, P)
```

Вот задание
Процентная ставка по вкладу составляет P процентов годовых, которые прибавляются к сумме вклада. Вклад составляет X рублей Y копеек. Определите размер вклада через год.

Программа получает на вход целые числа P, X, Y и должна вывести два числа: величину вклада через год в рублях и копейках. Дробная часть копеек отбрасывается.
прохожу курсы по программированию на пайтон самый новичёк прошу не сердится на глупейший вопрос

Comment: ошибка в операторе format

Comment: '{0}, {1}, {2}'.format('a', 'b', 'c')

Comment: так `print('({} + {}) * {}'.format(X, Y, P))` или 
`print(f'({X} + {Y}) * {P}')`

Comment: Скобка закрывающая не там: `print('({} + {}) * {} ').format(X, Y, P)` -> `print('({} + {}) * {} '.format(X, Y, P))`.

Comment: `print('{0:.2f}'.format((X+Y)*P))`

Comment: `format` применяется для объекта строк

Comment: 1 - вы пытаетесь применить format к результату функции print (None, т.к. print ничего не возвращает), а нужно применять к самой строке. 2 - если нужно вычислить результат, то это нужно выполнять не внутри строки, а снаружи, а результат уже форматировать при необходимости.

Answer (score 0):

Начнём с того, что к функции применять format нельзя.

Можно внести его в принт, так машина поймёт, что ты хочешь сделать.

```
    print(('({} + {}) * {} ').format(X, Y, P))
```

Однако, это функция **СТРОКИ**, они не могут подвергаться мат. операциям.

Т.е. лучше сделать так:

```
txt = '{} + {} * {}'.format(X, Y, P)
answer = (X + Y) * P
print(txt, '=', answer)
```

Если необходимо округлить до чего-то, то вместо print(answer) впиши:

```
a = round(answer, 2)

print(txt, '=', a)
```